# Having a problem with z-index and the transform skewX property on a div tooltip

Tags: html, css

Hello css programmers and programmers in general! I'm having a bit of a headache with this; I can't manage to position a tooltip above an image that has the same properties. This is one of the issues; 
https://prnt.sc/shovd7

As you can see the above doesn't overlap the last image. I don't understand why. I set an "r" class to configure the right side of the screen for position use really.

Here is the code for the tooltip;

```css
.tooltip {outline:none;position: relative;display: inline-block;}
.tooltip div {
    z-index: 4;
    display: none;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #252525;
    padding: 0px 15px;
    white-space: prewrap;
    width: 265px;
    font-size: 16px;
    float: left;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px -3px #ffffff, 0 0px 0px 0 rgba(255, 70, 70, 0.19);
    text-align: left;
    position: fixed;
}
.last{
    width: 25px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
 position:relative;
 z-index: 2;
}
.tooltip.r div {
    float: right;
 position: fixed;
}

.tooltip.r > img {
transform: skewx(-30deg);
}

.le{
    position: absolute;
}
.le.r{
 right: 183px;
 width: 89px;
 height: 139px;
 overflow-y: auto;
 transform: skewX(30deg); 
 padding-left: 20000px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 padding-right: 2px; 
 float: right;
}
a.tooltip:hover div{ 
 display: inline-block; position: absolute;}
```

```html
<div class="le r">
<a class="tooltip r" href="#">
   <img id="665" class="fl-r last" src="https://www.anime-blast.com//images/skills/665.png?">
   <div>
 <img class="point" src="./images/arrow_right.png">
                        <h1>Bodiless Suit of Armor</h1><p>- <b>Alphonse Elric</b> has 5 damage reduction.<i style="color:#BA2415;"> this skill ends when Alphonse Elric dies</i></p><p>- <b>Alphonse Elric's</b> damage will be increased by 10.<i style="color:#BA2415;"> this skill ends when Alphonse Elric dies</i></p></div></a>
<a class="tooltip r" href="#">
    <img id="665" class="fl-r last" src="https://www.anime-blast.com//images/skills/665.png?">
    <div><img class="point" src="./images/arrow_right.png">
      <h1>Bodiless Suit of Armor</h1><p>- <b>Alphonse Elric</b> has 5 damage reduction.<i style="color:#BA2415;"> this skill ends when Alphonse Elric dies</i></p><p>- <b>Alphonse Elric's</b> damage will be increased by 10.<i style="color:#BA2415;"> this skill ends when Alphonse Elric dies</i></p></div></a>
</div>
```

Finally my second problem is I set the tooltip within a div which holds a record of the last "abilities" used. You hover over and the description of this ability shows. 
https://prnt.sc/shozxl

Im trying to hide the scroller bar of this so I add a padding left, the issue is the padding overlaps the skills for the other player and im not able to click them, the window is divided in 2 and a footer. So if I set a z-index on the left wing of the screen it will hide the tooltip itself below the skill set for the character. Is there any work around for the scrollerbar or a fix for this current design. I am trying to optimize this to work for all browsers.

My project depends on you all!! Sorry for the confusion and if im repeating a question. I've looked around and really found no solution.

Comment: Bump, when I remove the transform skewX the tooltip works properly and the padding isn't applied to the left section. Any way around this? https://prnt.sc/shqc4w <- without the transform it allows for the hover over the left side and overlaps.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the scrollbar you just have to change the `overflow-x: hidden;` and `overflow-y: auto;` to only the singular `overflow: hidden;` style attribute:

```
.le.r{
    right: 183px;
    width: 89px;
    height: 139px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: skewX(30deg); 
    padding-left: 20000px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 2px; 
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Thank you friend! But this cancels the scrolling function.